# Send notification from systemd

Tags: notifications, systemd

At the end of a script I wrote, I want to send a notification to know when it ends. The content of the script is not important except the notification part.

Here is the important part of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

USER=<username>
USERID=`id -u $USER`

sudo -u $USER bash -c "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$USERID/bus notify-send -t 5000 -u normal -i /usr/share/icons/Adwaita/32x32/devices/drive-removable-media.png 'Ah! the element of surprise'"
```

When I run it from my terminal, it works well.

I've created a service file in `/etc/systemd/system` with the following content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test notification
Requires=home.mount
After=home.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/alexis/Personnalisation/Scripts/test.notification.sh
Type=oneshot

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

When I run it through `sudo systemctl start test.notification`, it works well.

The problem arise when systemd runs after I run `systemd enable test.notification`.

If I add other things in the script, they are done.

Is my service description wrong?
Is my notification instruction missing something?

Comment: Perhaps it ends before you've logged in?

Comment: for that simple example, that might be the case. But for the script I want to monitor, it waits until a drive is mounted. This drive is mounted manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that systemd runs with a minimal environment and not all envvar are known during the script execution. To make it work, I've change `bash` by `/bin/bash`.

I've found out what was wrong by running the script without the environment:

```
env -i /path/to/script
```

It returned the following error:

> sudo: bash: command not found

This error is self explanatory and helped me find the problem.